# How to make a function execute immediately after onclick in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input, textbox, caret

I want to change the caret position whenever the user clicks the mouse within a textbox. This is because I want to disable the possibility of the user changing the caret position; it has to stay constant and unchangeable.

But it seems that the function that `onclick` triggers is first executed about 0.3 seconds after the `onclick` actually occurs. There is a delay.

```
    input.onclick = function(){
        input.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }
```

`input` is the variable for the input field.

Comment: How are you measuring that time? Please may you share that? Usually the listener is called immediately

Comment: Do you need interactivity at all for the pointer in the textbox? If no you could try
 `input {
    pointer-events: none
}` 
in your css or 
`input.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
}`

Comment: It would be interesting to know _why_ you're trying to do this. It doesn't sound like good UX.

Comment: The time is just an estimation that I made from looking at how long it took the caret to change its position after I had changed it manually by pressing somewhere inside the textbox. And I do need some interactivity for the pointer in the textbox.

Comment: Click has to wait for the mouse down and up events. Are you using a mobile device?

Comment: I know it sounds a little odd what I am trying to do, but the reason is that I am creating a form of an online stopwatch; it is not a regular textbox if you will.

Comment: No, I am using my pc, and the browser is IE if that matters

Comment: An update: The issue is indeed that I am using onclick as opposed to onmousedown. But setSelectionRange() does not work if onmousedown is being used as opposed to onclick, so I need to figure out why that is.

Answer (score 0):

You might find more control with mouse events by also using the `onmousedown` event. `onclick` waits until the mouse button comes up. By the looks of it, could basically copy/paste another copy of this code, and just change `onclick` to `onmousedown`.

Comment: That actually does cut off some of the delay time. However, it is still there for some reason